# How to find minimum value in a cell whose value is always changing in Excel?

Tags: excel

In cell a1 value is always changing. I want to keep track of minimum value of a1 in a2. How is it possible?

Comment: Are you able to use VBA or can you only use Excel formulas/functions?

Comment: i can only copy and paste vba codes but suggested below code doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the value of A1 in A2.
2. Implement an event which responds to the change in A1.
3. When the event is fired, compare A1 to A2, and if A1 is smaller, store the new value.

---

This assumes there's already a value in A2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Dim a2val As Variant
        Dim a1val As Variant
        a2val = Range("$A$2").Value2
        a1val = Range("$A$1").Value2
        If a1val < a2val Then
            Range("$A$2").Value2 = a1val
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @RajuKumar Did you put the code in the correct Worksheet object? I don't like to say this, but the code works for me.